# Call QObject::thread() on QImage

Tags: qt, qimage, qobject

QImage doesn't seem to subclass from QObject. How can I invoke QObject methods on QImage? I'm interested in QObject::thread() method to invoke deletion in the appropriate thread.

Comment: you should treat QImage as a value object passing copies around as needed. It is optimized for that.

Comment: as @ratchetfreak said, `QImage` has no need to know in what thread it is. if you need, you could use a container. i dont think it is good practice to directly inherit your own class from `QImage` and `QObject`

Comment: What do you mean by "appropriate thread"? Data objects don't belong to threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's wholly unnecessary. Either:

1. Pass the image around as a value, it's cheap.
2. Use `QSharedPointer<QImage>` and pass that around. It's entirely unnecessary.

Internally a `QImage` is what amounts to a shared pointer to image data. That's why passing it by value is cheap, and that's why using a shared pointer to it is pointless.